# How to import Brave Wallet into Metamask?

Tags: metamask, wallets, private-key, mnemonic, brave-browser

I'm trying to write to an Etherscan contract, but Etherscan only supports Metamask and WalletConnect. The contract depends on my Brave address, so I downloaded Metamask and imported my Brave seed. Unfortunately, a different account without my funds showed up.

How can I import my Brave Wallet into Metamask?

Answer (score 1):

Brave uses a different Mnemonic system from the rest of Ethereum wallets, so you need to get the private key instead.

To get the Brave Wallet private key:

1. Go to brave://wallet/crypto/accounts
2. Click on the account name you want to export
3. Click the Pencil icon on the right
4. Click Private Key

To import it into Metamask:

1. Open your Metamask extension, click your account icon in the top right and select Import Account
2. Set the type to Private Key
3. Enter the value from the Brave Wallet private key

If the UI ever changes these options might be slightly different for you.